# random number generation of the form $k/(1+x)$

Tags: random-variables

I need to random numbers of the form $\frac 1 {(1+x) \log 2}$ over the interval $[0, 1]$. I know that I can generate this using inverse transform method. Are there any other methods beside it? Is there a way to generate this distribution using acceptance-rejection method or transformation method?

Comment: @m-stgt Yes, I want to use acceptance-rejection method or transformation methods.